# Why does this user not have an invitation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, null, invitation

I have a form that creates a `signed_user`. This is the first line of the form:

```
<%= form_for(setup_user(@signed_user)) do |f| %>
```

The setup_user is in my application helper:

```
def setup_user(user)
  user.tap do |u|
    u.build_invitation
  end
end
```

These are the model associations:

`signed_user` model:

```
has_one :invitation, :foreign_key => "sender_id"
```

`invitation` model:

```
belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'SignedUser'
```

So why is a user being created without an invitation? I checked my console and the user's invitation is nil...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a [nested form](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes). All the details are available in the article but basically make sure you use accepts_nested_attributes_for in your SignedUser model.

```
class SignedUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  has_one :invitation, :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invitation, :allow_destroy => true
  ...

end
```

If you want your form to modify attributes from the Invitation model (in addition to attributes from the SignedUser), you'll also need to use fields_for in your form. For example:

```
    <%= form_for setup_user(@signed_user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      // More user form fields

      <%= f.fields_for :invitation do |cf| %>

        <%= cf.label :event_name %>
        <%= cf.text_field :event_name %>

        // More invitation form fields

      <% end %>

      <%= submit_tag %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: i don't want the form to modify attributes from the invitation model. also, I tried adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :invitation, :allow_destroy => true` but this didn't work

Comment: You'll need to use fields_for in your form if you want the invitation attributes to be sent back to the server. Otherwise you could simply create your invitation record in the SignedUsersController#create method: u.create_invitation. Just make sure the u.save and u.create_invitation instructions are part of a transaction to avoid persisting inconsistent data. Even better, use an after_create callback in your SignedUser model to generate an Invitation record every time a new SignedUser record is created (no need to worry about transactions in this case).

Comment: after_create :create_invitation
...

private

def create_invitation; self.create_invitation; end

Comment: More on ActiveRecord callbacks here (more examples too): http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html. Hope this helps.